# Cannot call value of non-function type [UIColor]

Tags: swift

I have written this code into Swift but last line of code return this error message:

> Cannot call value of non-function type '[UIColor]'

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct Colores {
    let colores = [UIColor(red: 210/255.0, green: 90/255.0, blue: 45/255.0, alpha: 1),
        UIColor(red: 40/255.0, green: 170/255.0, blue: 45/255.0, alpha: 1),
        UIColor(red: 3/255.0, green: 180/255.0, blue: 90/255.0, alpha: 1),
        UIColor(red: 210/255.0, green: 190/255.0, blue: 5/255.0, alpha: 1),
        UIColor(red: 120/255.0, green: 120/255.0, blue: 50/255.0, alpha: 1),
        UIColor(red: 130/255.0, green: 80/255.0, blue: 90/255.0, alpha: 1),
        UIColor(red: 130/255.0, green: 130/255.0, blue: 130/255.0, alpha: 1),
        UIColor(red: 3/255.0, green: 50/255.0, blue: 90/255.0, alpha: 1)]


    func regresaColorAleatorio() -> UIColor{
        let posicion = Int(arc4random()) % colores.count
        return colores(posicion)
    }
}
```

Comment: well, i guess that's because you try to call `colors(position)` which is not a function (as the error says.). also note i fixed your abuse of non-english variables there.

Answer (score 3):

You make some syntax mistake. `colores(posicion)` should be `colores[posicion]`

```
struct Colores {
  let colores = [UIColor(red: 210/255.0, green: 90/255.0, blue: 45/255.0, alpha: 1),
    UIColor(red: 40/255.0, green: 170/255.0, blue: 45/255.0, alpha: 1),
    UIColor(red: 3/255.0, green: 180/255.0, blue: 90/255.0, alpha: 1),
    UIColor(red: 210/255.0, green: 190/255.0, blue: 5/255.0, alpha: 1),
    UIColor(red: 120/255.0, green: 120/255.0, blue: 50/255.0, alpha: 1),
    UIColor(red: 130/255.0, green: 80/255.0, blue: 90/255.0, alpha: 1),
    UIColor(red: 130/255.0, green: 130/255.0, blue: 130/255.0, alpha: 1),
    UIColor(red: 3/255.0, green: 50/255.0, blue: 90/255.0, alpha: 1)]


  func regresaColorAleatorio() -> UIColor{
    let posicion = Int(arc4random()) % colores.count
    return colores[posicion]
  }
}
```